# why input elements in react causes a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, ag-grid

**EDIT**
I 've created this blnkr instead to make things more cleaner and independent on third party library so I 've added some dumy `X` string to an array in a component ,
to reproduce the issue

- 1 - Go this blnkr :
  https://plnkr.co/edit/jG3HPOHFoBpFNy39?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview
- 2 - Click Tab Two button
- 3 - Click the `Grow` button few times
- 4 - Take a heap snapshot
- 5 - Click the `Grow` button few times  again
- 6 - **IMPORTANT**  Focus the input elment
- 7 - Unmount the component (by clicking Tab One again )
- 8 - Click (GC button) and take another heapsnapshot
- 9 - compare with the first one
  finally you will see the repeated `X` string under `concatenated string` field in the comparison which means the component that own this string is never cleared !

screenshot [image]

I 'm using ag grid to build highly scalable data grid and it consumes significant amout of memory so optimizing the memory leaks is somehing necessary on my end , I 've noticed that using the `<input type="text" />` and focusing or typing on it then destroying the react component doesn't acually remove the input element and its owner component from the js heap which causes a memory leak !
I 've created this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/18AQcdXgNIV1m6fW?preview
Screenshot of reproducing the issue (focusing the input element and then unmounting the component by clicking the `toggle` button and i can see many detached elements in the memory  , is there a workaround into this , i 've also noticed that this is common within react components using input elements never garbage collected
[image: This is screenshot of the memory snapshot]

Comment: You should really include with your question that you've made several [issues](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/6046) about this [already](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/6074) on the ag-grid GitHub. I don't think there's an actual problem here. Why does it matter that memory is used? That's what it's there for. It always goes back down eventually for me. What [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) is this causing you?

Comment: Hi @thirtydot , The problem here is that the memory allocated by the component doesn't free up after beging unmounted  because the input element is still being refrenced there , so i'm not sure if this issue caused by the browser or react itself and I 'v opened the issue there for ag grid to know if there's a workaround for this from their end

Comment: Assigning `[]` to `myArray.current` on unmount seems to clear the `(concatenated strings)`

Comment: @Konrad this isn't the solution i 'm looking for , because if we 've many objects or a third party library that creates many objects in such component , it will be a mess